# can't view a raster image (multiband satellite image) with image overlay plugin over leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, raster

i'm trying to view a raster image (multiband satellite image) ,with 8 bands , in a web mapping site using image-overlay (leaflet plugin) . i get the image extent blank . this is the raster file that i used

```
<html>
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=313D1A84155423E8&resid=313D1A84155423E8%21103&authkey=ADFZt66lh2yvK-g" width="98" height="120" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</html>
```

[raster_file](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=313D1A84155423E8&resid=313D1A84155423E8%21103&authkey=ADFZt66lh2yvK-g)

and the result viewed in the website [raster viewed in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNU8H.png)

this is the source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>raster</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [31,-8],
    zoom: 8,
  });
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        new L.LatLng(34.22,-8.68),
        new L.LatLng(32.01,-6.27));
    var overlay = new L.ImageOverlay("croplf3.tif", bounds
    );
    map.addLayer(overlay);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that a file in TIFF format? Remember that browsers don't have support for that specific format - you'll have to convert it to another image format.

Comment: yes it's tiff . which other formats support multiband raster imagery ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built in [ImageOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#imageoverlay) functionality.

```js
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
  new L.LatLng(34.22, -8.68),
  new L.LatLng(32.01, -6.27)
);

var overlay = new L.imageOverlay("croplf3.tif", bounds)
  .addTo(map);
```